# Yii2 DatePicker installation

Tags: yii2

Found documentation about this widget [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-datepicker.html) and library [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui).

Tried to install with Composer and failed: [image: Error screenshot]

Tried to copy `"yiisoft/yii2-jui": "~2.0.0"` to `composer.json` and then update Composer and failed again:

> Class 'yii\jui\DatePicker' not found

Is there any way to install this extension  without using Composer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0"` ? It is a *NPM/Bower Dependency Manager for Composer* that required by yii2. Before installing yii2-jui try this command, and then `composer update`